# Android - Navigate back to tabbed fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

My Action bar consists of two tabs (a list of businesses and a map of businesses). If someone chooses from the list I would like to hide the tabs and show that business' page. If the user hits back, the business fragment is popped and the tabs should be displayed again.

What is the best approach to get this working? So far with the following code I have an inexplicable recursive loop if I pop the business fragment :(

So picture this, I'm displaying the BusinessListFragment tab. I choose a business, swap fragments and in onPause() I set the navigation mode to standard. Hit the back key, and in the onResume() of the BusinessListFragment I have this:

```
    ActionBar ab = mHostingActivity.getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab.getNavigationMode() == ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD)
        ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Which is supposed to bring back the tabs, but the app freezes with a loop. The tabs are definitely still present. Maybe I'm doing something else strange in my code (I'm sure I'm not though), or maybe Android does something strange when the naviagtion mode is set?

Edit: I've learnt that simply setting the navigation mode to tabs seems to actually select the first tab - which I believe would explain the recursion. Interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Okay well this took a while to figure out but hopefully this will help future googlers :D

It seems the best practice is to never try and hide / show tabs by setting the navigation mode from within a tab fragment's onResume / onPause, or anywhere within it for that matter.

I therefore set the mode to Standard in the onResume() of the detail (business) fragment. Normally if there are no more hierarchical layers of navigation to traverse from within the detail fragment, it is fine to simply set the mode back to Tabs in the detail fragment's onPause() - accounting for back presses or up presses.

However in my case you can click on elements within the business page to launch another fragment (leaving a stack count of 3), meaning I cannot 'turn on' tabs within onPause(), and found the best solution was to do it within onDetach(). This should mean the tabs are only turned on when the detail fragment is actually popped from the stack.

Hopefully this solution is accurate, I have toyed with many ideas including back stack listeners and overriding onBackPressed, but for me this seems to be the best option.